# How can I creat like the picture?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiXTP.jpg)

Sorry for the language of that pics, it is korean.
I want to make a planner that can help me to be noticed my plan. As you can see the picture, it is a calender, and I can add some plan depend on a user. the korean meaning is my major of Uni. So it is just some schedule.
The problem is I don't have any idea how to make like that. The way to operate this app, I hope I can add my schedule on the specific dates like the pictures and, creat the interface like that. I can slide the planner and it leads the next dates. When the plan comes to me, it could notice me by sound.
I can't find the way how to code the function 'slide' and how change the months and dates automatically by sliding?

Answer (score 0):

I have ever create an application like this picture for my job interview, you can use recyclerview to show the date as horizontal. Then you should create database to showing data by date selected. Then showing the data as vertical using recyclerview after selected date. This is really simple apps.. Below is picture i have
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3SJJ.jpg)

Comment: hello, Sincerely thank you for your answer. I tried to follow your way but still, I couldn't finish If you allow, can I refer to your coding if you have the coding that you creat before? I want to refer to yours when I create mine..... please Do you mind sharing your coding with me?